# Cognito change phone_number before confirm via Phone

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I want to change `phone_number` attribute of user before they confirm via phone. My flow step:

1. User register by username, password, and phone number
2. User must be enter confirmation code received by the phone. In this step user want to change the phone number (wrong number or change the phone...)

2.1 In case the 1st phone number be wrong, the next phone number is correct -> only one confirmation code had been sent -> it works!

2.2 In case the 1st phone number and the next are correct -> have two confirmation code had been sent(1st - xxx, 2nd - yyy) -> User enter 2nd confirmed code, Cognito throws `CodeMismatchException: Invalid verification code provided, please try again.` error. User enter 1st code, user had been confirmed, but in Cognito system the user has `phone_number` is 2nd number and `phone_number_verified` is `true`.

I use `adminUpdateUserAttributes` to change `phone_number` of a user who has status is `UNCONFIRMED`. Confirmation code auto send after me call change phone number.

How to fix this?

**!!!Update**

Currently, I removed the feature `User can update their phone_number before they confirmed via phone` from my application.

It takes me about 5 days, I just want to memo my case.

When you try to update `phone_number` (or `email`) attribute, Cognito will send a confirmation to your phone (or email) in automatically, this is the first code - (1st - xxx), the code to confirm your new attribute value (not for user confirmation).

In the same time, logic code calls `resendConfirmationCode` function, it send the second code - (2nd - yyy), this is main reason only the second code working (we use `confirmSignUp` function to handle the code).

Comment: To confirm the scenario, you have 2 phone numbers: phone 1 and phone 2.  You sign up with phone 1 and use adminUpdateUserAttributes to change the phone number to phone 2.  The code you receive on phone 2 doesn't work to confirm the user, but the code you receive on phone 1 does and the confirmed phone number is phone 2?

Comment: @behrooziAWS
Yep! This is exactly my case. I think the confirm code of phone 2 is attribute verify code (not confirm signup code), the code auto send will have someone try to change phone_number (or email). How I can disable that SMS feature temporarily?

Answer (score 1):

I am on the Cognito team, same as behrooziAWS. After looking at your scenario, it does seem to be a bug on our side. I will mention it within the team so that we prioritize it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! You can read my comment in the question, it is not issue. Anything is working pretty, but my case is not normal.

Comment: Any update on this? Or is there a github issue somewhere that we could follow?

Comment: Stumbled upon exact same issue. 4 Years and it still persists, it a feature at this point ;)

Comment: Also ran into this today. Are there any news about this behaviour?

Comment: This seems to be still an issue?!?!

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked awhile ago but some people still having issues with verification code being sent and no way to verify the code on an account not confirmed yet so I found a solution that works for us.

Our auth flow is:

`SignUp -> OTP Screen -> Confirmed OTP -> Cognito Account confirmed -> Custom email sent to user to verify email address -> Update attribute email_verified = true`

On the OTP screen, we display the number OTP has been sent to, if it's the incorrect number, we allow the user to go back to signup page and change number and resubmit signup. We use a UUID for the user on cognito so as to allow a user to signup again without causing errors where account already exists but not confirmed.

This means we get two accounts with UUID in cognito, one being confirmed and one being unconfirmed with the only difference in the accounts is the phone number. We then get rid of unconfirmed accounts after a certain period. eg 7 days

Comment: Definitely a unique way to go about this. How do you process the unconfirmed accounts?

Comment: We can process the unconfirmed accounts by using the aws sdk, getting the status and creation of the account. If they fall within a date threshold and still in unconfirmed state, remove the account. You can use Lambda with cloudwatch event to scan users in the user pool every so often as much as you like, we just have it set daily to check up on the status

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else seeking the answer to this, what I ended up doing was writing a lambda that essentially checks if a user is unconfirmed, delete's the user and then signs them up again.  I originally went the updateUserAttributes route but it felt insecure in case a bad actor got access to the lambda and updated a confirmed users phone number to theirs.  If a user signups with a different username but the same number from a different account, it will invalidate the others users account.  Hence the logic below.

```
try {
            const userParams = {
                UserPoolId: process.env.userpool_id,
                Username: event.args.username
            };
            const { UserStatus } = await identity.adminGetUser(userParams).promise();
            if (UserStatus === 'UNCONFIRMED') {
                const deletedIdentity = await identity.adminDeleteUser(userParams).promise();
                if (deletedIdentity) {
                    const signupParams = {
                        ClientId: process.env.client_id,
                        Password: event.args.password,
                        Username: event.args.password,
                        UserAttributes: [
                            {
                                Name: 'phone_number',
                                Value: event.args.phoneNumber
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    const newSignUp = await identity.signUp(signupParams).promise();
                    if (newSignUp) {
                        response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {
                            newSignUp
                        });
                        callback(null, newSignUp)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                response.send(event, context, response.ACCESSDENIED, {
                    error: 'User not authorized to perform this action'
                });
                callback({error: 'User not authorized to perform this action'}, null)
            }

        } catch (error) {
            response.send(event, context, response.FAILURE, {
                error
            });
            callback(error, null)
        }
```