# What is the proper AWS Cognito Signup flow to include email verification and MFA with either SMS or TOTP based MFA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I would like to require users to sign up with a verified email, and then , additionally, with either, an SMS OTP based MFA, or a TOTP authenticator app based MFA.

The issue I'm having is that there does not appear to be a way to add an SMS verification flow, into the sign up process after they have verified their email, when we are attempting to enable their MFA method.

I see it is possible to pass the phone number here

```
Auth.signUp({
      username,
      password
      attributes: {
        email,
        phone_number
      },
    })
```

However at this point in the sign up flow, I do not know if the user wishes to do SMS or TOTP based multi factor authentication, therefore I do not know if I need their phone number to be verified. And even if I were to add phone number verification at this step, it would be a bit awkward for the user because they'd be verifying two things at once. I've not seen that type of a situation elsewhere, with any other sign up process and I'd imagine it would be confusing to the user to receive both an email and an sms verification code at the same time.

As I understand the Cognito signup flow, it is only after they have completed this step, and I attempt to sign in, and find that MFA must be set up, and SMS is selected as the MFA Type, that I know a phone number must be added and verified.

In other words, after attempting sign in, I expect to receive a response with something like this

```
"ChallengeName":"MFA_SETUP",
"ChallengeParameters":{"MFAS_CAN_SETUP":"[\"SMS_MFA\",\"SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA\"]"}
```

But by the time I've called

1. SignUp {Username: "example", Password: "exmaple", UserAttributes: [{Name: "email", value: "test@example.com"}]}
2. ConfirmSignUp {Username: "example", ConfirmationCode: "{code received in email}"}
3. InitiateAuth

I've already passed in the user's attributes and those that need verification have already been verified. It is only after this point, as of "InitiateAuth" that I get the response informing me that I need to run MFA setup.

And it's only after the MFA_SETUP response is received, that I can then show the user their MFA setup options, and only after they select SMS that I know that I need to initiate a  phone number verification flow.  However at this point, we are not fully authenticated, and so "Auth.updateUserAttributes" is failing. Note I'm using @aws-amplify for this Auth wrapper to the AWS cognito service API. I don't see it actually issuing a request before rejecting my request. It's possible that this is an amplify only constraint, and that Cognito would allow an attributes update call at this phase.

I tried calling

```
Auth.updateUserAttributes(partiallyAuthenticateduser, {phone_number: smsOtpPhoneNumber })
```

It returns this, again before actually issuing a request to cognito.

```
core.mjs:8400 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate
Error: Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate
    at CognitoUser.getSession (CognitoUser.js:1328:16)
    at Auth.js:1309:18
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1429:21)
    at AuthClass.userSession (Auth.js:1307:16)
    at Auth.js:1005:18
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1429:21)
    at AuthClass.updateUserAttributes (Auth.js:1004:16)
```

**EDIT:** if using CognitoUser.updateAttributes() which bypasses amplify, you still get

```
Error: User is not authenticated
    at CognitoUser.updateAttributes
```

This is called after Auth.signIn() or 'intiateAuth' and so the CognitoUser returned from that call is not considered fully authenticated.

We are are not fully authenticated, because we are pending their MFA confirmation. But we are trying to set that up, and we are trying to set it up with SMS, but we have not verified the phone number yet, because it was not clear, until this point in the sign up process, that a phone number verification would be necessary.

I considered holding off on issuing the "SignUp" request until after I knew their preferred MFA type, and then passing both the email and phone number into the attributes list of the SignUp call, but this would produce an awkward sign up flow where the user receives two verification codes, from two different sources and has to supply both of them to complete sign up. I would much prefer to distinguish between the initial sign up and email verification and the SMS attach and verify step. Also this flow ,where I'm gathering up data earlier in the flow, to submit a few steps downstream, would be possibly problematic if it were interrupted and the user had to resume or restart the sign up flow. ( **EDIT** It's actually worse because we can't actually complete TOTP secret generate, until after SignUp is called, so there is no way to do MFA configure, and then, once we know whether or not we need SMS verify, call SignUp. Sign up has to be called before we do TOTP setup. So if they selected TOTP , and we called sign up, and then they changed their mind, we'd have no way to revert to SMS because their account would now be created and partially authenticated with no verified phone_number attribute )

Another option  may be to disable the MFA requirement in cognito ( which requires generating a completely different user pool.... ) , so that the user can fully sign in, with no MFA , and then, I can have them add the SMS attribute, verify it and then set it as their preferred MFA , after having fully authenticated with no MFA step.  But I do not wish to give my users the option to use sign in without MFA. I could potentially find other ways to enforce that MFA is attached before allowing them to access resources but that seems cumbersome given that cognito should already be able to enforce this requirement.

Also, I'm concerned that even if I manage to initiate the user phone_number verification flow at the desired time in the process, that this initial attribute verification, will not be treated the same as the MFA Sign in / Confirmation value, and that the user would have to receive two text messages to complete the sign up flow. One to verify their SMS number, and one to actually use the number to provide their 2nd authentication factor. This is definitely not.. what we want.

All of this grief makes me think that I am attempting to implement a non typical sign up flow. With that in mind, What is the flow that cognito is expecting users to go through when they are attaching both an email address and an MFA, where that MFA is optionally an SMS based MFA but may be a TOTP App based MFA?

What I am expecting is this

Plant UML

```
@startuml
:User Provides Username, Password, Email;
:User Provides Receives Email;
:User Provides Email Verification Code;
:User Select MFA Option;
if (MFA Type?) then (SMS)
  :User Opt In to SMS;
  :User Submits Form with TN;
  :User Receives SMS Message with Code, HELP, STOP;
  :User Provides SMS Verification Code;
else (TOTP)
  :User Clicks to Generate TOTP Secret;
  :User Scans QR Code or Copies Secret to Authenticator App ( Mobile );
  :User Provides TOTP Verification Code;
endif
:User is Fully Authenticated;
@enduml
```

[image: Desired Sign Up Flow]

But from what I can see so far of Cognito's service interface, this would require some way to add a verified attribute after sign up, but before full authorization, which doesn't seem possible.

**EDIT:** Adding some doc references

SignUp ( Main question is, can we add a phone_number attribute after we have called this and set up the user, but before we've completed our first MFA authentication ? )

[signUp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#signUp-property)

Initiate Auth:  Responds with MFA_SETUP if we have not yet attached an MFA method. Note that we need to call this before we can generate a TOTP secret, so we have to cross this threshold in the flow before we can do TOTP setup, but if we decide to DO SMS setup, we have to have specified a phone number attribute before we arrived here, or at least that is how it appears right now.

[initiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#initiateAuth-property)

This method , at least when called via AWS Amplify, is not supported for a partially authenticated session.

[updateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#updateUserAttributes-property)

**UPDATE:** I don't think we'd actually call this method. "verifyUserAttribute" for the phone number, but we do still need to be able to ADD The phone number attribute. The reason is that [When a user successfully goes through the SMS text message MFA flow, their phone number is also marked as verified.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa-sms-text-message.html) this page indicates that the first time we use the phone_number for mfa, it also gets atomically verified. Which is what we want. We don't want the user to have to verify the number and THEN get another message to confirm sign in.

Again though, that doesn't solve the primary problem we have which is that we have not added the user's number as an attribute, because it wasn't known at the time where attributes were being gathered, if the user was choosing SMS or TOTP based MFA, and now we need to trigger an SMS based MFA message.

[veriyUserAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#verifyUserAttribute-property)

[getUserAttributeVerificationCode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#getUserAttributeVerificationCode-property)

**NOTE:** Interesting reference here on AWS Pinpoint for best practices. Now Pinpoint is not cognito and doesn't assume we are using cognito, but their example flow , at least at the time of writing, illustrates a flow where the username, password and email are collected, and then only after the user enables MFA and selects SMS, is the TN collected and SMS opt in submitted. That is the flow we are going for, except that we will not be giving users the option to chose to disable MFA.

[AWS Pinpoint Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-best-practices.html)

It seems this is a standard flow. But as of now it seems that cognito assumes that if SMS is supported as an MFA type, that phone numbers will always be collected.  OR that if sms is an optional MFA type, that sign in without an MFA will be tolerated, so that the phone_number attribute can be set later.

We definitely want to require MFA, but we definitely want the phone_number to only be required if SMS is selected as the MFA strategy.

**EDIT:** At this point, I believe my only options are

**A)** Require the Phone number always, but configure cognito to not automatically verify it.

This way it is only verified if they use it for MFA, and it is available for that MFA. As long as we disable the auto verify for phone number, we don't have to worry that we are not presenting them with the SMS opt in until they select SMS as their preferred MFA Option.

This is obviously not great because we don't want users to have to supply a phone number if they don't want to and frankly, we'd rather they use app based MFA anyway. It's not great to force all users to provide a phone number, for the sake of having a flow that supports users requiring this MFA option.

**NOTE:** Come to think of it, as I write this option out, how would we handle the scenario where the phone_number attribute was set incorrectly? If you are in the middle of sign up, and trying to add an MFA, and the phone number entered was entered incorrectly, how would we edit that attribute?  If we can't solve that then not even this is a viable option. It really seems like that should be something we can solve. Users should be able to change the number mid sign up , if they discovered they entered it incorrectly.

**B)** "Soft" Disable MFA requirement for login, so that we don't have to send the MFA verification code until after our first login, and we can then, once fully authenticated, add the phone_number attribute if desired and configure it for MFA. We'd then require "MFA" as a claim on any resource servers where claim requirements can be customized.

The problem with this is that, while we can probably gate access to our resource servers based on the requirement that they have an MFA claim on their access token, I'm not sure we can constrain access to other cognito services this way. Maybe with a cumbersome auth gateway or pass through lambda sitting in front of our identity provider, with similar scaling capacity, but ugh... And if we don't add that pass through, then in theory, an end user could setup an account, do a bunch of stuff, build up some account value, and then remove their MFA. They'd lose access to our resource servers but any not requiring the custom claim, such as cognito, would still allow access. Someone else could log in , without MFA and access anything not secured by the MFA claim.  This is not great and probably not an option we can consider.

**EDIT:** The key to this may be, how does AWS Cognito handle situations where the phone_number attribute is specified, and WRONG. The user finds they are unable to verify this attribute because they entered it incorrectly. Surely cognito has a procedure in place that allows the user, who is partially authenticated to mutate an attribute as long as it has not yet been verified.

Else the user risks getting into a state where they've claimed a unique username, but cannot complete signup due to a mistyped email or phone number. At which point a support call would be needed to get their account deleted or the attribute changed, and that is risky and expensive from a support perspective. However I'm inclined to believe at this point that this is how AWS would recommend we resolve this issue.. that is, we give up and the user calls into support and an admin fixes things. Which is not.. great.

If there is a way to mutate the attribute as long as it has not been verified, then that may be a pathway to also adding an attribute after the initial setup call but before authentication is completed.

**EDIT:** It's not looking good. Doing some reading on the more general question of, how do you change an attribute mid sign up. It seems you can't. And it appears to be a design oversight.

[Allow a user to fix phone number attribute during signup](https://repost.aws/questions/QUnbai89EJThyvfcvTMxgoxQ/allow-a-user-to-fix-phone-number-attribute-during-signup)

That post describes the problem pretty well

> "My cognito backed is set to require and confirm email and
> phone_number. In this case, Cognito will only send text messages to
> the given phone_number and depends on app logic to confirm the email
> address. However, during signUp(), the user can provide a valid but
> incorrect phone number (typo, landline, whatever) which must be
> corrected to complete the initial sign up. I don't see a way to let
> the user make corrections.
>
> Calling signUp() again with a corrected value returns an error because
> the unconfirmed user has polluted the cognito table. User "already
> exists". I can't have the app updateAttributes() of a user that isn't
> confirmed since they couldn't generate authorization tokens.
>
> What is the workflow here? Do I have to expose a lambda function that
> has the rights to delete unconfirmed users from the backend?"

First answer:

> "Reading over the documentation, uses cases, and rampant and varied
> complaining about Cognito and the quality of the Amplify library on
> github this is clearly a design oversight.
>
> The only way forward that I can see is to mis-use the Cognito
> interface and cover the deficiencies with lambda triggers..."

Another post here lists an adjacent issue. In their case they appear to have used the admin API to override the attribute mid sign up, so this is the " user calls into support and the support guy pulls the override lever and fixes it " pathway.

> "I use adminUpdateUserAttributes to change phone_number of a user who
> has status is UNCONFIRMED. Confirmation code auto send after me call
> change phone number."

In their case though, even then, after updating the attribute, if the prior phone number had been a valid number, just not the one the user meant to use , then the user was unable to confirm their sign up without the original code sent to the original number.

[cognito-change-phone-number-before-confirm-via-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193223/cognito-change-phone-number-before-confirm-via-phone)

This issue was actually responded to by a claimed AWS agent indicating it was an issue and that they'd get it prioritized. It appears based on recent comments that the issue is still not resolved.

What this means is even if we found a way to mutate the phone_number mid sign up, if a confirmation code had already been sent to the first number, the user would still be stuck, as changing the phone_number attribute would not allow them to enter the confirmation codes sent to that new number.

I would agree then that this appears to be design oversight.

It appears, that the way developers are working around this right now, in the event the number was entered incorrectly, is thy are sending the users back to create a new account. And then they are cleaning up unverified accounts after some length of time.

The problem with this of course is that the username will already have been allocated and claimed. They'd have to chose another username, and then try to change their username after the other account had been cleaned, and hopefully before someone else claims it. Naturally that is not a workable solution.

One solution another dev suggested was to use a UUID for the username. That doesn't really work because the user needs to know this unfriendly username to sign in until they are able to set their username.

You could have them sign in with email, but I've noted already that this can break if multiple accounts are claiming the same email. As well it should. I know we had one user during testing  that was unable to login with their email address, until we deleted one of the conflicting accounts that had the same email address. It may be that emails can be set to be unique once verified. I don't recall such a setting but it's possible, still we are deeply into a very convoluted work around and highly over complicated flow at that point. I'm not sure I want to go down that path.

Of note this may even affect users who have put in the wrong email. So even simple email verification may cause users to get stuck with a burned username if they've entered the wrong email.

Which means we may have to deal with this complex strategy of delaying username selection until sign up and verify are complete,  whether we want to or not.